# Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference. 13

Tags: sql-server, group-by

```
SELECT NumberOfUsers,'date' AS Date
FROM son.LicenseUsageStats
GROUP BY 'date'
```

table includes 4 columns

```
rownum | numberofusers | timestamp | date
```

table logs number of users every hour so each day there are several entries

attempting to capture number of users by month and getting error

> "Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference."

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please clarify: a) is it SQL? b) if so: which RDBMS you are using?

Comment: TY.yes SQL Srvr 2014

Comment: It's just hypothesis: I suppose than an aggregate function is forgotten in this code. Such as `COUNT` or `SUM`.  E.g. `SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumberOfUsers,'date' AS Date`

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumberOfUsers,'date' AS Date 
 FROM son.LicenseUsageStats
 GROUP BY 'date'

Comment: same error message received

Comment: Ah! `SELECT COUNT(*), date FROM son.LicenseUsageStats
 GROUP BY date` ? Note the absence of quotes around `date` in `GROUP BY`

Comment: wunderbar!!  you nailed it...thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're selecting the actual string `'date'` instead of selecting your date column. Replace it with

```
SELECT NumberOfUsers, [date] AS Date
FROM son.LicenseUsageStats
GROUP BY [date]
```

Although this still needs an aggregate function, such as `SUM()` for `NumberOfUsers` if you're grouping.